# Change value of a strings representing number

Tags: ksh, string, arithmetic

I have the following expression :

```
a="2013"
```

How can I change the value of `a` to `"2012"`.

Comment: it's not totally clear what you are askin. the simplest solution (`a="1012"`) is probably not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `$(())` for shell arithmetic:

```
a=$(($a-1))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either use the standard `$(())` as suggested by Joseph R., or, with some shells (`ksh`, `bash`, `zsh`), you can use `let`:

```
$ a="2013"
$ let a--; ## Or let "a=$a-1"
$ echo "$a"
2012
```

Answer (score 0):

A concise way using arithmetic expansion would be

```
a=$((a-1))
```

or simply

```
((--a))
```

Note that the latter syntax in not mandated by POSIX but is supported at least by `ksh` and `bash`.

Comment: `(( --a ))` without the assignment also works.